# Connect html contact us form with expressjs server side

Tags: html, node.js, express

Hi I'm new in web development I'm trying to write the backend code for contact us form but it keep giving me error:

My Html code for contact us form:

```
</div>      
        <div class="row">   
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                <div class="contact-form">
                    <h2 class="title text-center">Get In Touch</h2>
                    <div class="status alert alert-success" style="display: none"></div>
                    <form id="main-contact-form" class="contact-form row" name="contact-form" method="post">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                            <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" required="required" placeholder="Name">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                            <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" required="required" placeholder="Email">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                            <input type="text" name="subject" class="form-control" required="required" placeholder="Subject">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                            <textarea name="message" id="message" required="required" class="form-control" rows="8" placeholder="Your Message Here"></textarea>
                        </div>                        
                        <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                            <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" value="Submit">
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
```

and my backend code is

```
    var express = require('express');
    var logger = require('morgan');
    var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
    var pjs = require('ejs');
    var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
    var router = express.Router();


    var app = express();

    // Middleware
    app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
    app.use(express.static('public')); 
    app.use(logger('dev'));
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

    app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    // database query
    res.render('index');
     });


    app.get('/blog-single.html', function(req, res) {
    // database query
    res.render('blog-single');
    });

    app.get('/blog.html', function(req, res) {
    // database query
    res.render('blog');
     });

     app.get('/cart.html', function(req, res) {
    // database query
    res.render('cart');
     });

     app.get('/checkout.html', function(req, res) {
        // database query
        res.render('checkout');
      });

      app.get('/contact-us.html', function(req, res) {
        // database query
            res.render('contact-us');
        });

         router.post('/contact-us.html :contact-form', function(req,           res)          {
            var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
            service: 'Gmail',
              auth: {
            user: 'abm.rizk@gmail.com', // Your email id
        }

         })

          });

           app.get('/index.html', function(req, res) {
            // database query
           res.render('index');
          });

           app.get('/login.html', function(req, res) {
                // database query
            res.render('login');
              });

              app.get('/product-details.html', function(req, res) {
                // database query
            res.render('product-details');
           });

           app.get('/shop.html', function(req, res) {
            // database query
            res.render('shop');
             });

            app.get('/*', function(req, res) {
            // database query
            res.render('404');
           });


           app.listen(8080, function(err) {
                if (err) {
                console.log("Error");
                } else {
                console.log("Running on port 8080");
                    }
                  })
```

This is my full backend code and html i just post the contact us form so basically my problem is with

```
    router.post('/contact-us.html :contact-form', function(req,res){
            var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
            service: 'Gmail',
              auth: {
            user: 'abm.rizk@gmail.com', // Your email id
           }

             })

            });
```

In the console there is no error but one I browse :

My form:

[image]

but once I click submit :

[image]

Comment: What's the error that you are getting?

Comment: I know it seems to be a simple problem but I couldn't figure it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path of route is wrong. Alter to:

```
router.post('/contact-us', function(req,res){
    var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        service: 'Gmail',
            auth: {
                user: 'abm.rizk@gmail.com', // Your email id
            }    
     })    
 });
```

I noticed this problem on their routes, but it still does not work, post the console error output.

Comment: in the terminal there is no error but once I click submit in my page it show me this massage in the browser : Cannot POST /contact-us.html